# Confidence interval considering the division of 2 means with different CIs? Statistics

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the mean and its confidence interval (standard deviation and size of its sample) of 2 different data A and B. I want to divide A/B and get the confidence interval of its division. Is there a formula for that?

For example, I want to divide time (400 s +/- 20s) per size (10 m +/- 3m). What's the result, considering confidence interval?

Comment: Wrong stack? This is for the software Mathematica. Perhaps CrossValidated stack is what you're after?

Comment: Take a look at [Propagation of uncertainty - example formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulae)?

Answer (score 3):

In version 12 of *Mathematica*, there is the function `Around` which does what the link in the comment by @MarcoB does.  However, `Around` assumes that the covariance term is zero.

Statisticians use the term "Delta Method" rather than "Propagation of error" or "Propagation of uncertainty".

For your example if 20 and 3 represent standard errors:

```
Around[400, 20]/Around[10, 3]
(* Around[40., 12.165525060596439`] *)
```

More generally:

```
Around[m1, s1]/Around[m2, s2]
```

[image: Approximate ratio and associated standard error]